# How to edit CD Rip settings in Rhythmbox to improve mp3 quality

Tags: rhythmbox

I'M trying to edit the mp3 rip settings in rhythmbox in order to increase the quality to 320 kbs, but the edit button is locked in Ubuntu 12.04

http://ubuntuone.com/4QqbHZ20RmWWrRZynk2ctZ

Any help please?

Thanks.-

Comment: The current solution specific to this question was answered here along with the general idea of how it will be done. Any relevant answer here should likely wait till the SRU upgrade to see how it is applied, if a ~/.gstreamer-0.10/presets is created, ect. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1965432

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Already reported bug: http://launchpad.net/bugs/945987

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, just use Asunder. `sudo apt-get install asunder`. It works out of the box with fixed (up to 320 kbps) and variable bitrates. Though, I did have to go to preferences and change the CD-ROM device to `/dev/sr0`.